# Slack API - how to send multiple images so they are shown in a gallery

Tags: slack-api, image-gallery, slack-block-kit

When I send multiple images via api using blocks like this:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "image",
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please enjoy this photo of a kitten"
            },
            "image_url": "http://placekitten.com/500/500",
            "alt_text": "An incredibly cute kitten."
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please enjoy this photo of a kitten"
            },
            "image_url": "http://placekitten.com/500/500",
            "alt_text": "An incredibly cute kitten."
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please enjoy this photo of a kitten"
            },
            "image_url": "http://placekitten.com/500/500",
            "alt_text": "An incredibly cute kitten."
        }
    ]
}
```

Slack shows them like a separate blocks and doesn't combine them into a gallery:
[slack screenshot - API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rbkU.png)

When I upload them using Slack app in one message - it combines them into a gallery:
[slack screenshot - with gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfJg7.png)

I've tried blocks, attachments, third-party urls, permalinks after file.upload - the result is the same, Slack doesn't combine them into gallery.

**So, the question is - how do I make it that Slack shows several images in a gallery?**

Answer (score 10):

UPD:
Just got an answer from Slack developers support:
[slack dev support answer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSCYE.png)

> Unfortunately, horizontal/gallery formatting of images is not possible
> using the block kit builder. However, I'm going to go ahead and pass
> your email on to our product team so that they can take this into
> consideration for future updates.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment,

> [...] permalinks after file.upload [...]

this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63391026/1227632) might help (I also added this clarification there).

When uploading files and collecting their permalinks, you must link them in the `text` param in the [message payload](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/payload) (putting them in a mrkdwn block in the `blocks` param will not work).

In javascript, this looks like:

```js
const result1 = await web.files.upload({...})
const result2 = await web.files.upload({...})
await web.chat.postMessage({
  text: `Here are files in a gallery view <${result1.file.permalink| ><${result2.file.permalink| >`,
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It has helped me get across this blocker today ❤️

Comment: The upload API can be a little bit of a pain, but otherwise this method works perfect and looks exactly as one would expect.