# how to format Slack message with several files

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

Can somebody please advise on how to send a message to a channel with several files attached? I successfully uploaded files to slack, but having issues formatting my message.

I tried markdown message with `<file1.permalink| > <file2.permalink| >` but it looks ugly with silly `(edited)` note [image: sent from my app]

What I'm trying to achieve is for my message to look the same way, like when I send a message with files through the Slack client, with no stupid `(edited)` note [image: sent with Slack app]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the approach shared here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939261/send-multiple-files-to-slack-via-api) will help?

Comment: @sandra, it's exactly what I tried to do. It looks like the message is posted in two stages: first text with links, and then Slack adds files into the same message with `edit` event, so it's why I finish with my message been tagged with `edit`