# How to upload a text file to Slack without sharing it to a channel

Tags: slack-api

The [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/messaging/files/uploading) says:

> If you don't use the `channels` parameter, the `upload` method only "uploads" the file, hosting the file in Slack, but doesn't "share" the file anywhere.

That's exactly what I want, and my uploads appear to succeed, but the permalink URLs that Slack gives me for the uploaded files don't work.  If I supply nonempty `channels`, the URLs I get work, but that publishes the upload to the channel, which I don't want.

Is there a bug in the Slack implementation or is there something I don't understand?

More details follow.

---

I am using the Slack API to post a message that includes some context, which is a long plain text string.  The context is too long to include in the message itself, so I want to upload it as a snippet, and then publish a message that includes a link to the snippet.

I use the `files.upload` API endpoint to upload the context string:

```
            r = safe_slack_request(
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                data={
                    "content": full_pytest_context,
                    "filename": f"{fs.name}-context.txt",
                    "filetype": "text",
                    "channels": "",
                },
                endpoint="files.upload",
            )
```

This works, and returns a successful response that includes [the Slack `file` object](https://api.slack.com/types/file) I expect.  The object advertises an ID and a permalink URL.

Then I post my Markdown message which contains a link to the uploaded file:

```
    context_link = (f'<{r.json()["file"]["permalink"]}|(full context)>'
```

I incorporate the link into a markdown block in a message I publish with `chat.postMessage`.  The message is published to the channel `mjd-test` and it looks the way I expect:

[image: screencap of rendered markdown hotlink]

But when I click the link, it doesn't work!  The Slack "Files" sidebar opens with a message that says "This file was not found":

[image: As described]

If I manually paste the permalink URL into the browser's address bar, it still doesn't work:

[image: Slack says "There was a problem when trying to open this link"]

If I use the `files.info` API endpoint to look up information about the file, Slack agrees that it exists, and shows me the content I expect, but the permalink URL it gives me is the same one that doesn't work.

The result is the same if I use `"channels": None` or if I omit the `channels` POST variable entirely.

I can get the permalink to work if I include the target channel in the `channels` parameter of the `files.upload` method.  But this *also* publishes a preview of the context into the channel, which I don't want.

As a workaround, I can share the file in a dummy channel nobody cares about; then when I post a message with the permalink in the real target channel, it works.

Why doesn't the permalink URL work unless I share the file in a channel?  How can I link to a file I've uploaded without first sharing it somewhere?

Comment: Also relevant from the `files.upload` API documentation: "By default all newly-uploaded files are private and only visible to the owner. They become public once they are shared into a public channel (which can happen at upload time via the channels argument)." I don't see any way to do what you want to do. I saw your comment in the "multiple files" SO question - it only works there without the `channels` param, b/c when you post a slack message linking images in that special format, Slack just does the channel sharing for you. Same thing at the end of the day.

Comment: Btw have you tried the `files.sharedPublicURL` API? Just came across it, might be what you're looking for: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL