# Slack API: post a message composed by several blocks with files attached

Tags: slack-api

I can't find the way to post a message with files attached. I've verified that I'm able to upload files using `files.upload`, which gives me the id and permalink.

I've found examples [in other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106701/3524896) on how to "reference" the file to a message by linking it using its permalink, which adds a preview of the files but it can be cancelled by the user (a so-so solution).

And I've tested that, if a message has files attached, you can change those using the `chat.update` end point.

However, I do not find a way to post a message composed of several blocks and with files attached to it (not permalinked). I thought I may be able to do it using the files IDs once uploaded somehow but it does not seem to work. Has anyone archieved this?